# Double pointer of Mat initialization

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv, mat

I am trying to make a `Mat` array using OpenCV. The array is to store a number `N` of region of interest, and for each region I have to store the information of the last 5 frames. I'm trying to use a double pointer to `Mat`. The question is how do I initialize it?
I'm trying something like this:

In the header of the class: `Mat *Objs_avgwB[25];`

and to initialize in the source file: `vseg.Objs_avgwB = new Mat[vseg.avgw][25];`

Comment: It is not a `double` pointer but array of 25 pointers to `Mat`which you have declared. You can do something like this `Mat (*ptr)[25]` if you're sure that you have `25` elements per `row`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mucking around with pointers and `new`, a better option is to use the containers provided by the standard library. You don't need to worry about exactly how you'll initialize them, since they can be resized dynamically.

For each set of features in a frame, I would create a `std::vector` of `cv::Mat` objects, one for each region of interest. Then, use a `std::deque` to hold the features for each frame.

```
std::deque<std::vector<cv::Mat>> roi_history;
```

On each new frame, you would `push_back` each ROI onto the `std::vector` representing all ROIs in that frame:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> new_rois;
new_rois.push_back(roi1);
new_rois.push_back(roi2); // Etc...
```

you then pop off the oldest frame and push the new data to keep 5 frames in the queue:

```
roi_history.pop_back();
roi_history.push_front(new_rois);
```

You can then access each ROI in the history by using `operator[]` For example, to access the fourth ROI found in the previous frame (remember zero-indexing!):

```
cv::Mat my_roi = roi_history[1][3];
//                           ^  ^
//                           |  Fourth ROI
//                           |
//                           Most recent history (zero is current frame)
```

Comment: Yes, the conainers idea is a very good option, however I don't see how can I take into account there that there are N number of ROIs for which I have 5 frames queue. I see only a container for a single ROI, or can you exaplain it better?, how can I access each ROI

Answer (score 0):

The pointer which you have declared is not a `double(**)` pointer to `Mat` array.

Instead you can do this,

```
 Mat (*Objs_avgwB)[25] = new Mat[vseg.avgw][25];
```

which declares a pointer `Objs_avgwB` to a `Mat` whose first row has 25 elements in it.
You can use this if you're creating a 2-D array with 25 elements per row, because the return type of new in this case is `Mat(*)[25]`.

Also, don't forget to call the `delete[]` at the end.